# how to display multiple permissions at once in xamarin.forms?

Tags: c#, plugins, xamarin.forms, cross-platform, android-permissions

I want to show runtime permission popup for camera and location when the app starts or after splash screen.

I am using the NuGet package:https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/PermissionsPlugin

I have tried the below code on button click event.

```
private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await GetPermissions();
    }


public static async Task<bool> GetPermissions()
    {
        bool permissionsGranted = true;

        var permissionsStartList = new List<Permission>()
        {
            Permission.Location,
            Permission.LocationAlways,
            Permission.LocationWhenInUse,
            Permission.Storage,
            Permission.Camera
        };

        var permissionsNeededList = new List<Permission>();
        try
        {
            foreach (var permission in permissionsStartList)
            {
                var status = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(permission);
                if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
                {
                    permissionsNeededList.Add(permission);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }

        var results = await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionsAsync(permissionsNeededList.ToArray());

        try
        {
            foreach (var permission in permissionsNeededList)
            {
                var status = PermissionStatus.Unknown;
                //Best practice to always check that the key exists
                if (results.ContainsKey(permission))
                    status = results[permission];
                if (status == PermissionStatus.Granted || status == PermissionStatus.Unknown)
                {
                    permissionsGranted = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    permissionsGranted = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
        return permissionsGranted;
    }
```

Please give your suggestions or better approach for it.

Comment: Just line them up one after the other on `MainThread` and you should be good

Comment: I am fairly new to Xamarin so it would be great if you will provide sample code

Comment: Have you solved your problem or tried my solution?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to show runtime permission popup for camera and location when
>   the app starts or after splash screen.

If you want to permission popup for camera and location when the `app starts or after splash screen`.

You can call the `GetPermissions` method in `OnAppearing()` of your MainPage:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        bool a = await GetPermissions();
    }

    public static async Task<bool> GetPermissions()
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

**Note:**

1. As mentioned [here](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/PermissionsPlugin/issues/39), When you install `PermissionsPlugin` it will also install a file called "`MainApplication.cs`" into your Android app and that needs to be there.
2. And make sure you have selected the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` and `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`  permissions by right clicking `xxxx.Android` project--> `Properties` -->  `Android Mainfest` --> `Required permissions`.

I have uploaded a [sample](https://github.com/XfHua/Permissions-Xamarin.forms) and you can check. Let me know if it works.

Comment: App crashing, throwing thread end exception, any idea?